# Is there a way to enforce organisation wide Git user.name and user.email?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I'm curious to know how others have approached this or whether this is of any concern.

If someone has the wrong `user.name` or `user.email` set in their config, this will in turn create commits with them and may result in a mixture or usernames or emails within a repository.

In order to ensure consistency, it would be great if there is a way to set organisation wide polices for this so their name and work email are used. There is the ability to enforce an email validation check which ensures any commit emails end with `@example.com` but nothing for validating if that email or user name exists in Azure DevOps.

Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some git servers has hooks you can enable that enforce using the same name and email as the authenticating account. Check with Microsoft if that exists for Azure DevOps

Answer (score 0):

Some hosting platforms provide a way to run organization-wide CI checks.  I believe this is available, for example, on GitHub with GitHub Actions.  You could use such a feature to check every commit in a pull request to verify that it had author and committer emails that matched your organization's domain.

Some hosting platforms also let you use pre-receive hooks, which are also a possibility.  In addition, some hosting platforms have pre-defined checks for this, which you may be able to use.

You could do this by using something like `git log --format='%ae %ce' BASE...HEAD` (substituting `BASE` and `HEAD` for the proper values).

As for verifying `user.name`, you probably don't want to try to verify that.  That's traditionally a human's name, not a username, and as such people tend to use shortened or abbreviated versions of their legal name, as well as nicknames they're commonly known by at work.  That's in addition to various problems like Unicode normalization, where two visually identical strings aren't bit-for-bit equal.  In any event, trying to tell someone what their name is or whether or not it's correct is likely to be at the very least offensive.  I refer you to [the well-known article “Falsehoods Programmers Believe about Name”](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) for more details.